# pytorch: How do I properly initialize Tensor without any entries?

Tags: python, initialization, append, pytorch, empty-list

What I am doing right now is this:

```
In [1]: torch.Tensor([[[] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(5)])                     
Out[1]: tensor([], size=(5, 3, 0))
```

This works fine for me, but is there maybe a torch function that does this that I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
My use case is this:
I use this to aggregate Tensors with all dimensions the same and that dont have the empty dimension. I am using torch.cat:

```
# results start with shape (a,b,0)
results = torch.Tensor([[[] for _ in range(b)] for _ in range(a)]) 

for t in range(time):
    # r has shape (a,b)
    r = model(...) 
    # results now has shape (a,b,t)
    results = torch.cat([results,r.unsqueeze(2)],dim=-1)
```

Simply appending to a list is impractical for me as I have to do reshaping operations on `results` on every step (Im doing beam search).

One solution would also be to not initialize `results` until I have the first returned Tensor, but this feels unpythonic/wrong.

Comment: How does it work for you? What do you do with this tensor later on? Because this tensor is not actually useful as it is.

Comment: @Berriel see edit

Answer (score 1):

This can be another way depending on your usecase.

```
alpha = torch.tensor([])

In[5]:  alpha[:,None,None,None]
Out[5]: tensor([], size=(0, 1, 1, 1))
```

Otherways:

```
torch.tensor([[[[]]]]) #tensor([], size=(1, 1, 1, 0))
torch.tensor([[[[],[]]]]) #tensor([], size=(1, 1, 2, 0))
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work for me as I need to have some of the nonzero dims larger 1

Answer (score 1):

You have the [torch.empty](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.empty.html) function :

```
torch.empty(5,3,0)
>>> tensor([], size=(5, 3, 0))
```

is a tensor without any entry

Comment: torch.empty() doesnot create an empty tensor. see this https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.empty.html

Comment: also this: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/difference-between-torch-tensor-and-torch-empty/32831/7

Comment: You're completely right, I apologize. I misunderstood what the OP was looking for. `torch.empty(0,1,1,1)`still produces the same result as your code I think

Comment: @Mughees None of these methods actually initialize the tensor. Using a dimension as 0 with `empty`, `zeros`, `ones`, and so on will produce the same result of your answer and this one. Check `.tolist()` result. In none of them you can actually set an element of the tensor.

Comment: @Berriel I mean, at this point the actual question would be "what does it mean for a tensor to be initialized without any entry ?" Mughees' answer and mine just aimed at creating a tensor with the same weird dimensions as OP's tensor I think

Comment: @trialNerror exactly... I just asked that in the comments.

Comment: @trialNerror You're right, I should have clarified. I edited my question to explain a bit